# How to choose appropriate "base" when manipulating problems pertaining to percentages?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, percentages

I am having headaches whenever question requires choosing **base** appropriately when manipulating percentage related problems. I am sure I have not made any sense so far, so let me choose an example problem first:

> A number is increased by $20\%$ and then again increased by $20\%$. By what percent should the increased number be decreased so as to get back the original number?

My initial solution was like:

Let there be number $x$ which is increased sequentially twice by $20\%$. So the difference between increased number and init number $x$  would be: $120\% 120\% x - x $.

Now what to choose as base (increased number or init number $x$ ?) to make the ratio (part to whole) and then convert it in to percent?

This was just an example of problem I often face, so I would welcome any **concepts/analogy** which will make whole base selection procedure easy. Thanks.

Comment: It would be better to just consider the increased value of $x$, namely $1.2\cdot1.2\cdot x$ (not the difference). If this increased value is decreased by $y\%$, the final value is $(1-y/100)\cdot(1.2\cdot1.2\cdot x)$. But you know this later value is just $x$. So you have $(1-y/100)\cdot(1.2\cdot1.2\cdot x)=x$. Now solve this for $y$ (note the $x$'s cancel).

Answer (score 1):

Always consider a "percent increase" of $n$ as multiplying *the current number* by $1 + n/100$, and a "percent decrease of $n$ as multiplying the current number by $1 - n/100$.

Always use the last calculated number as a "base". In this case, suppose your number is 100. Increasing it by 20% twice gives you 144. Then, calculate the percentage that *144* needs to be decreased to bring it back to 100, which is about 30.55%, rather than the 44% you might have gotten by using 100 as the "base".

Comment: In short, use the "increased number".

Comment: will you theory apply to this question : `If A's salary is 20% less than B's salary. By how much percent is B's salary more than A's ?` ?

Comment: @Mr.Anubis Yes. B's salary is 25% more than A's.

Comment: It seems working in this case too (which is hard to see where is last value calculated etc) , I mean your theory may work but it's not actual way to solve the problem/thinking of problem to solve. Also I am still not touching the concepts here I believe

Comment: In order to determine that base, always determine which value the percentage operation is being performed on. (This gets into grammar as well.) For example, in the sentence "B is 20% more than A", A is the value being increased by 20%.